# "I met the man whose car I had tinkered with" OR "I met the man whose car had been tinkered with by me"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, relative-clauses, subject-verb-agreement

- I met the man whose car I had tinkered with.
- I met the man whose car had been tinkered with by me.

which is the correct sentence?
can we use another subject for the subject of a relative clause? -> (***whose car*** **I** had tinkered with)

Comment: The second one does not make any sense to me.

Comment: At first I read the second one as "had been tinkered with _by_ me", which would be technically correct. But the first one is simpler and more natural.

Comment: They are both fine. It's okay here to end the sentence with a preposition unless you are writing something formal.

Comment: Your example sentence is weird, perhaps in a way you don't realize.  People who are not expert mechanics "tinker with" cars. People who know what they're doing, professional mechanics, "work on" cars. It's unusual that a stranger would entrust their car to be "tinkered with" by someone they had never met.

Comment: @TimR Agreed. Reading the example sentence, I would assume that the speaker had tinkered with the owner's car without their knowledge, and probably illegally.

Comment: The #2 choice is so roundabout that it could work as a joke: "I met the man whose car had been tinkered with. By me, that is!"

Comment: @timr Hmm, not necessarily. Even if we accept your distinction, which I think is debatable, perhaps he was riding in the car with a mutual friend when it broke down and he had to "tinker" with it to get it going again. Or a million other scenarios. Without more context we can't say.

Comment: @Jay  Let's ignore the infinite scenarios that might make *tinker with* viable and focus on the likely possibility that a non-native speaker might not understand the connotations of "tinker with". Happy to discuss that, if you think professional mechanics wouldn't take offense if you described their work as "tinkering".

Comment: @TimR Hmm. I think it's problematic to say, "If we take this sentence totally out of context, it might possibly, if interpreted a certain way, be illogical. Therefore, the writer is an idiot who didn't know what he was talking about." When interpreting a sentence, ESPECIALLY one without context, I think we have to give the writer the benefit of the doubt, such as by considering scenarios where it would make sense.

Comment: @timr I don't know any professional auto mechanics personally. But I wouldn't be surprised if a pro mechanic said, "Yeah, the by-the-book solutions didn't work on this car, so I had to tinker with it." As a professional software developer, I certainly wouldn't be offended if someone referred to me as "tinkering with a program".

Comment: @Jay   Corner cases don't cause us to throw out the usual connotations of the word or pretend they don't exist.

Comment: @timr Well, I don't want to turn this into a running argument so this will be my last post on this. If someone said, "My 90-year-old grandmother did such-and-such", it would be nonsense to reply, "Few people live to be 90 so you must be mistaken or lying when you say your grandmother is that old." ESPECIALLY when the person isn't trying to prove anything, but just mentioning it in the course of making some other point. If the OP was trying to prove something about the word "tinker" here, maybe I'd take what he said with a grain of salt. But that's not his point, so no reason to attack that.

Comment: @Jay The gist of my earlier comment was that **tinker** has connotations of fussing about with something when one isn't a pro at making the repair, and that it would be unusual to entrust one's car to someone one had never met, so he could tinker with it. I suspected the OP might not be aware of those connotations. You said my distinction was debatable and spun a yarn that might justify entrusting one's car to someone one had never met. You missed the main point and went down a rabbit hole, and with this final yarn about a 90-year-old grandma, it seems you have not yet emerged from it.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence sounds natural.

The second is wrong. You could fix it grammatically by adding:

> I met the man whose car had been tinkered with **by** me.

However, it doesn't sound natural. Changing the agent of the action from 'I' to 'me' in the restrictive clause makes it weird because you've already started the sentence in the active voice with '***I** met the man..*'

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, both are valid, and the first is more natural. But that's partly because the same people ("I" and "me") are involved. One could imagine a sentence for which it's the better choice, e.g.:

> I met a man whose house was built by Frank Lloyd Wright.

This seems a better choice than "I met a man whose house Frank Lloyd Wright built."

Comment: "Frank Lloyd Wright built" hangs off the end of that sentence like a cantilever. :-)

Comment: Yes it sounds right after he edited in line with my advice.

Answer (score -1):

Both are grammatically correct and mean the same thing. The first uses active voice and the second uses passive voice. We generally use passive voice when we want to emphasize the object of the verb, the thing being acted on, rather than the subject, the thing doing the acting. In this case, there's no good reason to emphasize the car over the "I", so I wouldn't use passive voice here, but it's valid.

Comment: The passive can equally be used when we want to emphasize the agent. "That car wasn't worked on *by me*. It wasn't *me* who overfilled it with transmission fluid and ruined the transmission."  Or Bonner's Frank Lloyd Wright example.